# azure-cli returns error when importing publishsettings file

Tags: node.js, azure

While trying to import my publishsettings file with Windows Azure Command Line Interface/Tool, Azure CLI, I'm getting the following error message:

Assertion failed: 0 && "buffer encoding specified but string provided", file src\string_bytes.cc, line 309

node version: v0.10.6

azure-cli version: 0.6.16

Any ideas/workaround would be appreciated

Comment: just out of interest which azure command did you use to access your publish settings file? also what command line are you using to import the file?

Comment: Yeah ive got this same problem. Using OSX so i cant really use azure without the azure-cli :(

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this would be to file an issue in th team's repo:
https://github.com/windowsazure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat

Could you also try with the latest CLI to see if the problem still repos ?

If so, could you shoot me an email: andrerod AT microsoft DOT com and i'll follow up with you to try to figure out what's wrong.

Thanks!
Andre