# Error w/ Azure CLI on importing publish settings file

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012, azure

This is similar to the issue [this SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790162/azure-cli-returns-error-when-importing-publishsettings-file) was having except I'm getting a different error for the same behavior.

- I downloaded the publishsettings file from azure and
- Issued this command in the azure cli: `azure account import <MySite>.azurewebsites.net.PublishSettings`

and I got the following error:

```
{ name: 'AssertionError',
  message: undefined,
  actual: 'UNIVERSAL-primative-0',
  expected: 'UNIVERSAL-primative-6',
  operator: '==' }
AssertionError: "UNIVERSAL-primative-0" == "UNIVERSAL-primative-6"
```

...*Shortened for brevity. Let me know if you'd like the full stack trace*...

I wasn't particularly anxious to wrap this node project in a VisualStudio project, but I think in a pinch, I could and just format the publish settings from within VS. But if there is a way to do this correctly, I'd prefer that.

Comment: @JeffWilcox Thanks sir, I was pulling the project specific publishsettings file, not the azure site download publishsettings file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you get the file? Were you using the following command to get it?

```
azure site download
```

It seems like you are using the publishsettings file of an Azure Web Site while xplat-cli expects the publishsettings file of the subscription.

There are kinds of 2 publishsettings files. And yeah, it's confusing.

Comment: Yeah, you nailed it... I was using the portal to go to the specific web site and then download that publishsettings... So you're exactly right... When I did the azure site download it downloaded a different publishsettings file and that one went through correctly